# Android Gridview Increment Issue

Tags: java, android, gridview, increment

Question has been answered see below for a detailed answer on how to solve the problem.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int val, long arg3) 
    {   

        if(gameCounter > maximum)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrats you finished the game" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `val` when the code enters `onItemClick`? Also what is `count` equal to?

Comment: val is the position of the view, and count is actually gameCounter sorry for the confusion !

Comment: Any more help would really be appreciated I seem to have hit a brick wall with this :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your count is probably never greater than max.

I suspect you actually want

```
if(gameCounter>max) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrats you finished the game" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It appears you are still having issues, so I think it would help if you posted up the Array of  whatever you are trying Integer.parseInt().

As others stated without insight into the data it's hard to guess because there appears to be a logical flaw in the comparison.

Comment: Hi I have made the edit though i'm not sure why counter is never greater than max as the counter gets incremented once the user selects the appropriate value. so once the user selects all values in order the gameCounter should be greater than max